# UIViewController with thumbnails of photos stored in array

Tags: iphone, thumbnails, photos

I'm new to iPhone development. I have a task to create array of photos (I'll use loop for this) and I need to have 10 thumbnails of photos on one screen. So the questions is how to create the thumbnails of photos? thanks

Comment: You want them scrolling?

Comment: no, just 10 thumbnails on the screen

Comment: Well I should ask you then , [What Have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: [creating thumbnail of an image programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621487/creating-thumbnail-of-an-image-programmatically)

Comment: thank you, anonymous=) I'm trying now to create UIImages for UIBttons now but exploring other options too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to make this.
First is to create ten buttons with small images (UIImage for each UIButton)
Another way is to use [KTPhotoBrowser classes](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser) but since you are a beginner you may find it complicated a little bit, but you may try of course, it's nicely documented.
Regards